# Remove Facebook Login Product from dashboard

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a Facebook canvas app, and I made a test app.  Somehow, I accidentally added the "Facebook login" product to the test app, but I don't want it.  Is there a way to remove the "Facebook login" product from the app?

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can disable both login flows there, if your app doesn't need them.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm accepting CBroe's answer above that this can't be done, as there doesn't seem to be any way to do it through the FB Dashboard and FB's developer support is virtually non-existent.  Because it's a test app, it's not hard to just make a new test app, which is what I think I'll do.